# Override Markdown within Jekyll website git hub

Tags: git, markdown, jekyll

I'm writing content for a website (using **markdown**)

I have to put the following string: *Service_Operational_Conduct*

But because of **markdown**, it changes it to

> service*operational*conduct

Is it possible to display the original text and turn markdown off for the single string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to 'escape' the underscore, to tell the Markdown parser that you don't mean 'italic'.

The escape character can vary between Markdown parsers, but usually it is  the character `\`.

So try writing `Service\_Operational\_Conduct`, otherwise look in the documentation of your parser.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want kramdown to parse something, you can do :

```
{::nomarkdown}Service_Operational_Conduct{:/}
```